# how to get the logs into a memory stream and then into a file in python

Tags: azure, logging, blob

I want to get the logs into a memory stream and then write it into a file in python.
I wrote this code.

```
 stream = io.StringIO()

 logging.info("Service is starting..")

 connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;'
  
 #create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
 blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

 container_name="cloudops-resources"
 log_blob_name = 'mylogs17.log'
 blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=log_blob_name)


 # move the file pointer to the beginning of the stream
 stream.seek(0)

 # upload the logs to the blob storage
 print(stream.getvalue())
 blob_client.upload_blob(stream.getvalue(), overwrite=True)
```

it's printing the logs in the console , but not printing into a file.The file is empty.
Can someone please help me to solve this?

**PS:**
This is my full code after changing according to the below answer:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import pandas as pd
import re
from azure.data.tables import TableServiceClient
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, Border, Side, Alignment, 
Protection, Font
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,BlobClient, 
ContainerClient
import logging
import  sys
import io
import logging.handlers
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

def main(inputblob: func.InputStream, outputblob: func.Out[bytes]):

# create a memory stream to store the logs
stream = io.StringIO()

# create a logger and add a StreamHandler to write logs to the memory stream
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# create another StreamHandler to write logs to the console
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)

# create a RotatingFileHandler to write logs to a file
file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('mylogs19.log', maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=5)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

# set the logging level to INFO
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# log a message
logger.info("Service is starting..")

# upload the logs to blob storage
connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;'
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_name="cloudops-resources"
log_blob_name = 'mylogs19.log'
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=log_blob_name)

# move the file pointer to the beginning of the stream
stream.seek(0)

blob_client.upload_blob(stream.getvalue(), overwrite=True)


#create the container client
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()


in_blob_name = re.sub('cloudops-resources/', '', inputblob.name)
for blob in blob_list:
    if (blob.name != in_blob_name):
        pass
    else:     
        logger.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                    f"Name: {inputblob.name}\n"
                    f"Blob Size: {inputblob.length} bytes")
               
        # Set up the connection to the Azure Table storage account
        table_service_client = TableServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

        # Get a reference to the table
        table_name = 'runtimedocument'
        table_client_document = table_service_client.get_table_client(table_name)

        # Query the entities in runtimedocument table
        INOs_from_runtimedocument = list(table_client_document.list_entities(select=["InvoiceNo"]))
        Status_from_runtimedocument = list(table_client_document.list_entities(select=["Status"]))

        INOs_from_runtimedocument_list = []
        for x in range(len(INOs_from_runtimedocument)):
            INOs_from_runtimedocument_list.append(INOs_from_runtimedocument[x]["InvoiceNo"])

        Status_from_runtimedocument_list = []
        for y in range(len(Status_from_runtimedocument)):
            Status_from_runtimedocument_list.append(Status_from_runtimedocument[y]["Status"])

        # Query the entities in runtimeedi table
        runtimeedi = ['100302308549','100302308550','100302308551','100302308552','100302308553','100302308554','100302308555','100302308556',
                    '100302308557','100302308558','100302308559','100302308560']

        # Query the entities in runtimeemail table
        runtimeemail = ['100302308552','100302308553','100302308554','100302308555','100302308556','100302308557','100302308558','100302308559',
                    '100302308560','100302308561','100302308562','100302308563']

        # Query the entities in runtimefile table
        runtimefile = ['100302308557','100302308558','100302308559','100302308560','100302308561','100302308562','100302308563','100302308564',
                    '100302308565','100302308566','100302308567','100302308568']

        # Query the entities in runtimeprint table
        runtimelocalprint = ['100302308567','100302308568','100302308569','100302308570','100302308571','100302308572','100302308573','100302308574',
                            '100302308575','100302308576','100302308577','100302308578']

            
        df0 = pd.read_excel(inputblob.read())
        logging.info(f"{df0}")

        #Opening a new workbook and a worksheet
        wb = Workbook()
        sheet = wb.active

        #Defining column width
        sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 20
        sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 15
        sheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = 10
        sheet.column_dimensions['D'].width = 10
        sheet.column_dimensions['E'].width = 10
        sheet.column_dimensions['F'].width = 10
        sheet.column_dimensions['G'].width = 10
        sheet.column_dimensions['H'].width = 22
        sheet.column_dimensions['I'].width = 19
        sheet.column_dimensions['J'].width = 19
        sheet.column_dimensions['K'].width = 19
        sheet.column_dimensions['L'].width = 19
        sheet.column_dimensions['M'].width = 19

        # Add a header format.
        font1 = Font(name='Calibri',size=11,bold=True)
        font2 = Font(name='Calibri',size=11,bold=False)

        fill = PatternFill(start_color='ECC4A0',
                        end_color='ECC4A0',
                        fill_type='solid')

        border = Border(
                left=Side(border_style='thin', color='00000000'),
                right=Side(border_style='thin', color='00000000'),
                top=Side(border_style='thin', color='00000000'),
                bottom=Side(border_style='thin', color='00000000'))

        alignment=Alignment(horizontal='center',
                            vertical='center',
                            wrap_text=True,
                            shrink_to_fit=True)
                            

        protection = Protection(locked=True,
                                hidden=False)

        #Adding column headers
        hA = sheet['A1']
        hB = sheet['B1']
        hC = sheet['C1']
        hD = sheet['D1']
        hE = sheet['E1']
        hF = sheet['F1']
        hG = sheet['G1']
        hH = sheet['H1']
        hI = sheet['I1']
        hJ = sheet['J1']
        hK = sheet['K1']
        hL = sheet['L1']
        hM = sheet['M1']

        hA.value = "InvNo from Ecophon"
        hA.font = font1
        hA.border = border
        hA.alignment = alignment
        hA.protection = protection

        hB.value = "Payer"
        hB.font = font1
        hB.border = border
        hB.alignment = alignment
        hB.protection = protection

        hC.value = "Document"
        hC.font = font1
        hC.border = border
        hC.alignment = alignment
        hC.protection = protection

        hD.value = "EDI"
        hD.font = font1
        hD.border = border
        hD.alignment = alignment
        hD.protection = protection

        hE.value = "E-mail"
        hE.font = font1
        hE.border = border
        hE.alignment = alignment
        hE.protection = protection

        hF.value = "File"
        hF.font = font1
        hF.border = border
        hF.alignment = alignment
        hF.protection = protection

        hG.value = "Print"
        hG.font = font1
        hG.border = border
        hG.alignment = alignment
        hG.protection = protection

        hH.value = "Check Invoice"
        hH.font = font1
        hH.border = border
        hH.alignment = alignment
        hH.protection = protection

        hI.value = "runtimedocument status"
        hI.font = font2
        hI.fill = fill
        hI.border = border
        hI.alignment = alignment
        hI.protection = protection

        hJ.value = "runtimeedi status"
        hJ.font = font2
        hJ.fill = fill
        hJ.border = border
        hJ.alignment = alignment
        hJ.protection = protection

        hK.value = "runtimeemail status"
        hK.font = font2
        hK.fill = fill
        hK.border = border
        hK.alignment = alignment
        hK.protection = protection

        hL.value = "runtimefile status"
        hL.font = font2
        hL.fill = fill
        hL.border = border
        hL.alignment = alignment
        hL.protection = protection

        hM.value = "runtimelocalprint status"
        hM.font = font2
        hM.fill = fill
        hM.border = border
        hM.alignment = alignment
        hM.protection = protection

        greenfill = PatternFill(start_color='C0FED5' , end_color='C0FED5', fill_type='solid')
        yellowfill = PatternFill(start_color='FDF4BB' , end_color='FDF4BB', fill_type='solid')
        redfill = PatternFill(start_color='CD362F' , end_color='CD362F', fill_type='solid')
        pinkfill = PatternFill(start_color='FEB9CF' , end_color='FEB9CF', fill_type='solid')

        #Iterating through every row 
        invoice_no_list = []
        payer_list = []
        length = (len(df0))

        for i in range(len(df0)):

            div = df0.at[i, 'Div']
            inv = df0.at[i, 'Inv no']
        
            div_str = str(div)
            inv_str = str(inv)

            #concatanating division and invoice no from the input file
            Invoice_No = div_str + inv_str
            invoice_no_list.append(Invoice_No)
            cellNo_InvoiceNo = "A"+str(i+2)
            A = sheet[cellNo_InvoiceNo]
            A.value = Invoice_No

            #Slicing the " ' " in the payer column
            payer = df0.at[i,'Payer']
            payer_modified = payer[1:] 
            payer_list.append(payer_modified)
            cellNo_payer = "B"+str(i+2)
            B = sheet[cellNo_payer]
            B.value = payer_modified

            #Checking whether the Invoice nos are in runtimedocument
            cellNo_document_existence = "C"+str(i+2)
            C = sheet[cellNo_document_existence]
            C.border = border
            if Invoice_No in INOs_from_runtimedocument_list:
                C.value = "Exists"
                C.fill = greenfill
            else:
                C.value = "N/A"
                C.fill = yellowfill

            #Finding Index Positions of duplicate invoice numbers in runtimedocument
            def find_indices(INOs_from_runtimedocument_list, Invoice_No):
                indices = []
                for idx, value in enumerate(INOs_from_runtimedocument_list):
                    if value == Invoice_No:
                        indices.append(idx)
                return indices
                
            duplicates = find_indices(INOs_from_runtimedocument_list, Invoice_No)
            
            cellNo_status_document = "I"+str(i+2)
            I = sheet[cellNo_status_document]
            I.border = border
            I.alignment = alignment

            #printing error status of relevant invoice numbers in runtimedocument
            for d in duplicates:
                if(Status_from_runtimedocument_list[d]=="error"):
                    I.value = "error"
                    I.fill = pinkfill
                else:
                    pass

            #printing ok status in the remaining cells in runtimedocument
            if (i <= length):
                if (I.value == None):
                    I.value = "ok"
                    I.fill = greenfill
                else:
                    pass


            #Checking whether the Invoice nos are in runtimeedi
            cellNo_edi_existence = "D"+str(i+2)
            D = sheet[cellNo_edi_existence]
            D.border = border
            if Invoice_No in runtimeedi:
                D.value = "Exists"
                D.fill = greenfill
            else:
                D.value = "N/A"
                D.fill = yellowfill

            #Checking whether the Invoice nos are in runtimeemail
            cellNo_email_existence = "E"+str(i+2)
            E = sheet[cellNo_email_existence]
            E.border = border
            if Invoice_No in runtimeemail:
                E.value = "Exists"
                E.fill = greenfill
            else:
                E.value = "N/A"
                E.fill = yellowfill

            #Checking whether the Invoice nos are in runtimefile
            cellNo_file_existence = "F"+str(i+2)
            F = sheet[cellNo_file_existence]
            F.border = border
            if Invoice_No in runtimefile:
                F.value = "Exists"
                F.fill = greenfill
            else:
                F.value = "N/A"
                F.fill = yellowfill

            #Checking whether the Invoice nos are in runtimelocalprint
            cellNo_localprint_existence = "G"+str(i+2)
            G = sheet[cellNo_localprint_existence]
            G.border = border
            if Invoice_No in runtimelocalprint:
                G.value = "Exists"
                G.fill = greenfill
            else:
                G.value = "N/A"
                G.fill = yellowfill

            if (i<=length):
                cellNo_Check_Invoice = "H"+str(i+2)
                H = sheet[cellNo_Check_Invoice]
                H.border = border
                if(D.value == "N/A" and E.value == "N/A" and G.value == "N/A"):
                    H.value = "Investigation needed"
                    H.fill = redfill
                elif(D.value == "Exists" and E.value == "N/A" and G.value == "N/A" and I.value == "error"):
                    H.value = "Investigation needed"
                    H.fill = redfill
                elif(D.value == "Exists" and E.value == "N/A" and G.value == "N/A" and I.value == "ok"):
                    H.value = "Investigation not needed"
                    H.fill = greenfill
                else:
                    pass

        #Saving the output file as a temporary file
        with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp:
            wb.save(temp.name)
            temp.seek(0)
            stream = temp.read()

        #Saving the output blob 
        try:  
            outputblob.set(stream)
        except:
            logger.info("An error occurred.")
        else:
            logger.info("Output blob is saved successfully.")

logger.info("Service stopped")
```

This is what I got in the console.:

```
For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2023-04-19T04:20:27.576Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance 
ID '00000000000000000000000057786450'.
[2023-04-19T04:20:37.721Z] Executing 'Functions.BlobTrigger' 
(Reason='New blob detected(LogsAndContainerScan): cloudops- 
resources/inputs/Input_file123.xlsx', Id=c5bee9f7-b5a4-4f39-a796- 
e89a56f3ce94)
[2023-04-19T04:20:37.728Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 44a4282a- 
2b88-4ee9-a6e0-340591426977, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2023- 
04-19T04:20:37.000+00:00, BlobCreated: 2023-04- 
19T04:20:36.000+00:00, BlobLastModified: 2023-04- 
19T04:20:36.000+00:00
[2023-04-19T04:20:43.834Z] Service is starting..
[2023-04-19T04:20:43.851Z] Service is starting..
[2023-04-19T04:20:46.657Z] Request URL: 
'http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/cloudops- 
resources/mylogs19.log'
Request method: 'PUT'
Request headers:
    'Content-Length': '22'
    'x-ms-blob-type': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
    'Accept': 'application/xml'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.15.0 
Python/3.9.11 (Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0)'
    'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': '8ec178c6-de69-11ed-8732-c84bd64e0240'
    'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
A body is sent with the request
[2023-04-19T04:20:46.762Z] Response status: 201
Response headers:
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    'Content-MD5': 'REDACTED'
    'Last-Modified': 'Wed, 19 Apr 2023 04:20:46 GMT'
    'ETag': '"0x8DB408D730486A0"'
    'Server': 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
    'x-ms-request-id': '95f71a05-7c1e-4a9f-a895-05877c222386'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-request-server-encrypted': 'REDACTED'
    'Date': 'Wed, 19 Apr 2023 04:20:46 GMT'
[2023-04-19T04:20:48.221Z] Request URL: 
'http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/cloudops-resources? 
restype=REDACTED&comp=REDACTED'
Request method: 'GET'
Request headers:
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'Accept': 'application/xml'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-storage-blob/12.15.0 Python/3.9.11 (Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0)'
    'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': '8fb1109b-de69-11ed-a827-c84bd64e0240'
    'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
No body was attached to the request
[2023-04-19T04:20:48.261Z] Response status: 200
Response headers:
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
    'Server': 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
    'x-ms-request-id': 'b2da8bb4-3648-4583-90fb-b130e2801308'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'Date': 'Wed, 19 Apr 2023 04:20:48 GMT'
[2023-04-19T04:20:48.344Z] Python blob trigger function processed 
blob 
[2023-04-19T04:20:48.347Z] Name: aac-cloudops- 
resources/inputs/Input_file123.xlsx
[2023-04-19T04:20:48.351Z] Blob Size: None bytes
[2023-04-19T04:20:50.878Z] Python blob trigger function processed 
blob 
Name: cloudops-resources/inputs/Input_file123.xlsx
Blob Size: None bytes
[2023-04-19T04:20:50.880Z] Request URL: 
'http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/runtimedocument()?$select=REDACTED'
Request method: 'GET'
Request headers:
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'DataServiceVersion': 'REDACTED'
    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=minimalmetadata'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': '9145dc84-de69-11ed-8b7c-c84bd64e0240'
    'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
    'Date': 'Wed, 19 Apr 2023 04:20:50 GMT'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-data-tables/12.4.2 Python/3.9.11 (Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0)'
    'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
No body was attached to the request
[2023-04-19T04:20:52.294Z] Response status: 200
Response headers:
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8'
    'Server': 'Windows-Azure-Table/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
    'x-ms-request-id': 'df8bccff-3f00-466b-b3dd-1cf4c785457b'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'X-Content-Type-Options': 'REDACTED'
    'Date': 'Wed, 19 Apr 2023 04:20:51 GMT'
[2023-04-19T04:20:52.322Z] Request URL: 
'http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/runtimedocument()?$select=REDACTED'
Request method: 'GET'
Request headers:
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'DataServiceVersion': 'REDACTED'
    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=minimalmetadata'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': '92243631-de69-11ed-8e3e-c84bd64e0240'
    'x-ms-date': 'REDACTED'
    'Date': 'Wed, 19 Apr 2023 04:20:52 GMT'
    'User-Agent': 'azsdk-python-data-tables/12.4.2 Python/3.9.11 (Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0)'
    'Authorization': 'REDACTED'
No body was attached to the request
[2023-04-19T04:20:53.399Z] Response status: 200
Response headers:
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8'
    'Server': 'Windows-Azure-Table/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
    'x-ms-request-id': '75adb78c-08df-43f8-8c3f-42f8d633babe'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'X-Content-Type-Options': 'REDACTED'
    'Date': 'Wed, 19 Apr 2023 04:20:52 GMT'
[2023-04-19T04:20:53.612Z]         Inv dt  Div     Inv no  Job 
number        Payer
0   2023-02-17  100  302308549         NaN    '04022160
1   2023-02-17  100  302308550         NaN    '04025173
2   2023-02-17  100  302308551         NaN    '04024867
3   2023-02-17  100  302308552         NaN    '04024867
4   2023-02-17  100  302308553         NaN    '04024867
..         ...  ...        ...         ...          ...
255 2023-02-17  100  302395104         NaN       '12551
256 2023-02-17  100  302395105         NaN       '12551
257 2023-02-17  100  302395106         NaN       '12551
258 2023-02-17  100  302395107         NaN  '0351000867
259 2023-02-17  100  302395108         NaN     '0303503

[260 rows x 5 columns]
[2023-04-19T04:20:57.336Z] Output blob is saved successfully.
[2023-04-19T04:20:57.341Z] Service stopped
[2023-04-19T04:20:57.348Z] Output blob is saved successfully.
[2023-04-19T04:20:57.353Z] Service stopped
[2023-04-19T04:20:57.740Z] Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger' 
(Succeeded, Id=c5bee9f7-b5a4-4f39-a796-e89a56f3ce94, Duration=20208ms)
```

How can I get this all the logs which printed in the console to my log file?
And why some logs are printed twice?(ie:Output blob is saved successfully, Service stopped)

Answer (score 0):

***You need to use the method  below to log into the memory stream and use the below code to upload the logs in the blob file:-***

**Code 1:-**

```py
import  io

import  logging

from  logging.handlers  import  RotatingFileHandler

from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient

  

# create a memory stream to store the logs

stream = io.StringIO()

  

# create a logger and add a StreamHandler to write logs to the memory stream

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)

logger.addHandler(handler)

  

# create a RotatingFileHandler to write logs to a file

file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('mylogs17.log', maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=5)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)

  

# set the logging level to INFO

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

  

# log a message

logger.info("Service is starting..")

  

# upload the logs to blob storage

connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=strgaccountname;AccountKey=xxxxxxOv2mQxJQQqEZWQ4o+AStEutucA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

container_name="containername"

log_blob_name = 'mylogs17.logs'

blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=log_blob_name)

stream.seek(0)

blob_client.upload_blob(stream.getvalue(), overwrite=True)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Portal Blob file:-**

[image]

Code 2:- This code writes the log in the terminal as well as creates a new file and adds it in the storage account as blob:-

```py
import  io

import  logging

import  sys

from  logging.handlers  import  RotatingFileHandler

from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient

  

# create a memory stream to store the logs

stream = io.StringIO()

  

# create a logger and add a StreamHandler to write logs to the memory stream

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream)

logger.addHandler(handler)

  

# create another StreamHandler to write logs to the console

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)

logger.addHandler(console_handler)

  

# create a RotatingFileHandler to write logs to a file

file_handler = RotatingFileHandler('mylogs178.log', maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=5)

logger.addHandler(file_handler)

  

# set the logging level to INFO

logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

  

# log a message

logger.info("Service is starting..")

  

# upload the logs to blob storage

connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=strgaccountname;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxk+Ov2mQxJQQqEZWQ4o+AStEutucA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

container_name="containername"

log_blob_name = 'mylogs178.log'

blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=log_blob_name)

stream.seek(0)

blob_client.upload_blob(stream.getvalue(), overwrite=True)
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**File added to Azure Storage account like below:-**

[image]

Comment: It worked!thank you. But, all the logs printed in the console are not printing in the file.only "Service is starting" is printed.I 've updated my full code in the question.Can u have a look please?@SiddheshDesai